# How the input method can request 'updateCursor' event?

Tags: android, android-input-method

we are implementing custom input method service and we are interested
in receiving cursor update events. The documentation of
InputMethodSession's updateCursor() says:
"*This method is called when cursor location of the target input field
has changed within its window.  This is not normally called, but will
only be reported **if requested by the input method**.*"

How the input method can request this event?

Thanks in advance,

Andriy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is unimplemented. In the `TextView` implementation, calling `updateCursor` is conditional on `InputMethodManager.isWatchingCursor`, which is helpfully defined as follows:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the current input method wants to watch the location
 * of the input editor's cursor in its window.
 */
public boolean isWatchingCursor(View view) {
    return false;
}
```

Luckily, you can detect cursor movements using `onUpdateSelection`, although they will be given to you as a logical position within the text rather than a Rect.

Comment: `onSelectionChanged()` does not suit to me because I need to know the precise position of cursor on the screen, not relative cursor position in the text :) On the other hand `isWatchingCursor()` returns `false` only in Google's default implementation. Some Android vendors do return `true` there. E.g. HTC and LG.

Comment: Can you link to the source code of those alternative implementations?

Answer (score 1):

From API level 21 (Lollipop) there is a way to do it:

- Override [`onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo(CursorAnchorInfo cursorAnchorInfo)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo(android.view.inputmethod.CursorAnchorInfo)
- and call [`inputConnection.requestCursorUpdates(int cursorUpdateMode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html#requestCursorUpdates(int))

after you got the inputConnection.

The `onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo` will be called every time the cursor's position has changed.